# How to pause image download using glide in android

Tags: android

I want to pause image downloading and resume downloading. Here is my code

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://cfile2.uf.tistory.com/image/114DCE3E4D6456E52E6A5F").into(imageView);
Glide.with(this).pauseRequests();
```

It is supposed to be stopped and it has to be not shown in imageview. (The size of image is 10MB so it's size is big enough it takes for a while to be downloaded). Before the download of this image is completed, I called pasueRequest. However download never stops and the image shows up on the imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However download never stops and the image shows up on the imageview.

If you know the size of the image already, avoid the loading.

Comment: What I want to really do is that I want to download really big size of image and I want to pause when click button is clicked and resume download again when click button is clicked again. So I want to make the request pause but pasueRequest function does not work. I have no idea how to use it. Please help